# Returning a dummy json response

Tags: javascript, html

What I intended to do seemed simple at first sight but I've been unable to finish off. I have a javascript code that creates an array and uses JSON library to create my json response which is stored in a javascript variable. I put this code into a HTML file on my server. I just want my app to receive this code as JSON when doing a get request to the page. Nevertheless, I do not know how to serve this response.

I've seen lots of pages doing requests from javascript, but I would just like to have a dummy Rest service. I call the the page and receive back this little json code. I know how to implement this using a servlet but it looks unncessary to me to do that when data is a dummy test. Later on, I will implement the real service when I have more information about it but that's out of question.

```
//Simplified example    
<html>
<script>    
var tArray = <- //Complex logic executed in the server to create an array with the response so please, I CANNOT create just a .json
var tResponse = JSON.stringify(tArray);
//How do I return tResponse to the app requesting this page as if it were a rest service
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

The code shown is not my code. It is just a way to explain visually what I want to achieve. Please do not review that, just assume that it works and create a javascript response. I just want to know how to serve back a JSON response.

Comment: I believe you wanted to use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: You need to call `JSON.parse` on strings, not on arrays

Comment: Huh? Why would you wrap JSON in a script in a HTML file? Just serve the JSON only.

Comment: @Bergi Please, let's imagine that there is a very complex logical process in javascript that gets some information and once processed, it is parsed into a JSON. I have ALL that done. I just need to serve that back to the app.

Comment: Either, you do the "complex logical process in javascript" *in* your app and serve only the input to that (in an appropriate format), or you do it with serverside javascript and serve the result as JSON.

Comment: @Bergi You explain what I want, and what I ask. I do not get why nobody has been able to provide so far a few links or basic tutorial of how to return a json response from a javascript serverside app. Like if it were a Java servlet which generates a response.

Comment: @Capagris: But a serverside app is no HTML file as in your example? Do you use Node.js or some other environment, or don't you know about that at all?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer is actually just:

```
[]
```

Store in a file with extension `.json` and serve with content type `application/json`.

Comment: Thanks but your reply is contained in my question! If I knew how to do that, I would not have asked. First, [] is not enough, I have mentioned this already! I have some logic that must be executed in javascript before creating the JSON object. Second, I do not know how to tell Javascript on the server side to serve a response with that content type.

Comment: I thought you just want to have a "dummy REST service, that returns a constant string"? (»I know how to implement this using a servlet but it looks unncessary to me to do that when data is fixed and dummy.«) To me this implies a constant string, and that is what I have put in my answer.

Comment: If, for instance, you are running Node.js on your server, you can convert JavaScript objects to their JSON string representation with `JSON.stringify(obj)` (e.g. `JSON.stringify('["dummy string inside array"]')`)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider creating an empty JSON object.

tArray = {};

But it wont be an array anymore  :)

Comment: No! It is a very simplified example! The javascript code is big and private. I am just asking to imagine that I converted the result into JSON and now I want to serve it back to the user. Can I do that from the javascript code or html file? Any attribute or functionality?

Comment: I would go with knittl's comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
     var json = {a:1,b:2};
     document.write(JSON.stringify(json));
</script>
```

You can try this , This will write an json variable into string in a document . If you request to this page it will return the response .

Comment: I tried this option. When I did the get request over the file. I got all what is above as a string. It did not get evaluated! It may not be proper, but I'd be fine with your approach if the returned string would be what is written in the document

Comment: @Capagris , You can JSON.parse(String) to parse the json in javascript .